# python pisa generating black box for non ascii chracter in PDF

Tags: python, pisa

I want to generate a PPF using Python PISA Library but when i am trying  for non ASCII character its displaying black box in PDF.

It would be really great if someone help me here.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding=utf8

import ho.pisa as pisa
import StringIO
import sys

data = """
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>%s</p>
    </body>
 </html>
 """
text = '秋子明子晶子'

filename = "test5.pdf"
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(StringIO.StringIO(data % text),file(filename, "wb"),         encoding='utf-8')
```